# How do I turn a loop into a vector-based code?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, vectorization

I need to split a dataframe into N parts which shoud have a given length ("proglen").
I created a for-loop which gives me the desired result as a list of Dataframes.
Now I want to change the **for-loop to a vector based code**.

I'm not sure how to convert a loop into vector based code in R.

```
obslen = 600 ;proglen = 50 ; N = 50 ; testdat <- list()

for (i in 1:N){ 
  test <- df[df$d >= df$d[obslen + i * proglen] &
                    df$d < df$d[proglen + obslen  +i * proglen],]
  testdat[[i]] <- test
}
```

The variable $d has the type Posixct.
The result should contain N Dataframes. 
These dfs start at the day [obslen + i * proglen] and have the length "proglen".

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please provide a sample of your dataframe e.g. with `dput()`.

Comment: Maybe using `split()` in base is smart. `sp <- ceiling(seq(nrow(df)) / proglen); split(df, sp)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost similar to what you have done, just replaced by `lapply` and a little bit more readable. This will give you a list of data frames. This can also be done with recursive function but will be difficult to understand (in my view).

```r
lapply(1:N, function(idx){
  this_idx <- obslen + idx * proglen
  next_idx <- obslen + (idx + 1) * proglen
  df[this_idx:next_idx, ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are distinct then you can always use the `split` function:

```
testdat <- split(df[obslen + seq(1, N * proglen), ], rep(seq(N), each = proglen))
```